# Are there any built-in color swatches or color palette?

Tags: add-on, color

Are there any add-ons (or any other way) to get color swatches? In Coreldraw, Illustrator or any vector software we have color swatches.

[image]

- Ready made color shades, no need of mixing.
- We can have a fixed value for a specified color (red, green, blue, etc.).
- We can directly apply a fixed color value on a mesh.

How can I have a color swatch or is there any add-on available to use it?

Comment: Here is a quick cheat. Split the window and set as UV/Image editor, click new and Select a Colour Grid (or open your favourite swatch image). Then when ever you need a colour use the Eye Dropper and select from your image.

Comment: @rob But the problem is the image if it has a high resolution but yet to eye dropper not do the 100% job

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any inbuilt add-on. But you can use this free add-on. http://www.blenderskool.cf/kaleidoscope/

Answer (score 1):

The Import-Export: Import Palettes built-in Add-On allows you to use .ase format swatch palettes from Photoshop or Krita.

Comment: I tried to download attach the .ase file getting error in 2.92. error link image : https://imgur.com/a/NdUdhTs. Downloaded the .ase file from here : https://www.patternfly.org/v3/styles/color-palette/index.html